# Magento 2 : How to Get Visitor Data & Store Detaills in Database

Tags: magento2, customer, frontend

I want to get visitor data when visitor visit magento website. In visitor detail, I want to get IP address, browser name , Operating System Name , First Visit Time, & Last Visit time. How is it possible? This Feature must working on all page of magento website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will Google analytics, or any other analytics tool, not suffice for This?

Comment: no some time we have custom requirement . currently i have one requirement like this that i added as a new question